# SPCalendarView problem switching between days/weeks SP2010

Tags: calendar

I use SPCalendarView control as part of my UserControl in WebPart. Does anybody have problem switching between days/weeks in daily/weekly view in SPCalendarView control? There are no problem with switching months (when I'm inheriting System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart and set EnableV4Rendering to false; when I inherited Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebPartPages.WebPart and set EnableV4Rendering to true I was unable even to switch between months), but when user tries to switch days nothing happens (well, happens post-back and view for same day/week is been loaded). How did you resolve this problem? Sorry for my English.

I found that problem is in JavaScript code which changes selected date: when I'm viewing months it appends ...?CalendarDate= to request string, but when I'm in daily view, it leaves ?CalendarDate= unchanged and appends &date=, which seems to have no influence on displayed content. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found solution. If you will face the same problem, you could add block such as

```
if(Page.Request.QueryString["date"] != null)
   _view.SelectedDate = Request.QueryString["date"];
```

to your Page_Load method. Thread is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Although you got the answer, I thought of pasting this reusable code. This method could be used to change the view of SPCalendarView

```
        private string GetViewType()
    {
        string viewType = string.Empty;
        if (Page.Request.QueryString["CalendarPeriod"] != null)
        {
            switch (Page.Request.QueryString["CalendarPeriod"].ToString().ToLower())
            {
                case "day":
                    viewType = "day";
                    break;
                case "month":
                    viewType = "month";
                    break;
                case "timeline":
                    viewType = "timeline";
                    break;
                default:
                    viewType = "week";
                    break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
         viewType = "week";
        }

        return viewType;
       }
```

After you have this method in your class,  You can just call the above method to switch ViewType of SPCalendarView

```
            _calendarControl = new SPCalendarView();
        _calendarControl.ViewType = GetViewType();
```

Hope this helps someone in need.

Thanks,
Sudhir Kesharwani